# Why does findElements by tag name return a list of null values, instead of web elements?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a method for locating elements in java selenium. It sorts on several parameters, but the first thing it does, is to find all of the elements with a given tag name, in this case 'input'. This method has worked for many months now, but suddenly it behaves strangely.

Code:

```
String tagName = "input";
List<WebElement> baseWebElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName(tagName));    
for(WebElement oneWebElement : baseWebElements){
    System.out.println("oneWebElement "+ oneWebElement);
}
System.out.println("base elements = " + baseWebElements.size());
```

There are supposed to be 12 input elements. Here is the console output:

```
oneWebElement null
oneWebElement null
oneWebElement null
oneWebElement null
oneWebElement null
oneWebElement null
oneWebElement null
oneWebElement null
oneWebElement null
oneWebElement null
oneWebElement null
oneWebElement null
base elements = 12
oneWebElement null
```

I do not understand how this can happen. The code is so easy to read, and I can't find any logical reason to why this is happening. Does anyone have a clue about what is going on here?

Comment: Try to debug your for-in loop and see what is actually in there

Comment: Ìt's a list of null values. The findElements-method simply returns a list of nulls. It didn't before, and I have never heard of anything like this. I have specifically narrowed it down to the findElements-method just not returning what I expect that it would.

Comment: @KjetilNordin Please share the HTML Code also

Comment: @Siva I am on it. It is going to take some time though, as I need to simplify it down, and anonymize it. I can say as much as it is a simple username-login menu, which scrambled input elements generated dynamically with new id's every time. They are hard to identify programatically, which is why we have this custom function that retrieves all input elements, and refine them. Getting the list of base elements by tag name has never ever been a problem until now though...

Comment: It is not necessarily a list of null values. It could be a list of values whose `toString()` method returns `"null"`.